# How to solve this Iran TST 2014,second exam, problem？

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This Problem is Iran TST 2014, second exam, day 2 ,problem 3

> Consider $n$ segments in the plane which no two intersect and between their $2n$ endpoints no three are collinear. Is the following statement true?
>   Statement: There exists a simple $2n$-gon such that it's vertices are the $2n$ endpoints of the segments and each segment is either completely inside the polygon or an edge of the polygon.

It is said the answer is:Yes? why? I can't get this $2n$-gon such this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Joining the points would form a polygon. And the segments would itself be n of 2n edges of the polygon. But the polygon may be concave or convex. And we mostly do not consider concave polygons. But if you are considering them then yes because the half edges are itself the segments because edge joins 2points of polygon and that's what segments are.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I’ve found is “No”.

The condition to form a 2n polygon using the segments is that it closes

This only happens if all segments are sloped such as the sum of the slopes is zero while the side lengths are still sized to close the polygonal line. The only way to obtain such a unique distribution is to of an decomposed polygon.

Comment: The $2n$-gon has $2n$ sides, but you are only given $n$ line segments, and they don't even all have to be used as sides of the polygon, so there's no slope requirement.